# Prepare validation script

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation, devexpress-mvc

I am using Devexpress MVC controls for developing. One time I wanted to validate dynamically loaded form. So I used this [approach](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B205378/callbackpanel-client-validation-does-not-work). But now I cannot understand why should I use this:

```
function PrepareValidationData() {
  var form = $('#CityEditForm');
  if (form.executed)
    return;

  form.removeData("validator");
  $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
  form.executed = true;
}
```

Why should I use `form.executed` property? Unfortunately googling didn't help.

Comment: What is your real task? The aforementioned code may be already not actual...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding. The executed property is just showcase what can be done. If you make a little tweak, you prevent multiple parsing and similiar stuff.

> In this particular code, the condition have a little to no meaning and it should work
>   without it.